# Chart.js - how do I call an update function of the unnamed chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js2

I have quite a few charts I initialize like below:

HTML:

```
<div class="chart chart-one"></div>
<div class="chart chart-two"></div>
```

JS:

```
var $charts = $('.chart');

$charts.each(function() {
    new Chart($(this), {...});
}
```

Then I need to update the dataset of some of them and call the `update` function:

```
var currentChart = $('.chart-one');

...

currentChart.update();
```

I get the following error:

> chart.update is not a function

This probably happens because I should call an `update` function on the chart instance itself, not a jquery object, but mine are unnamed so I am not sure how to get this instance?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to put your second classes as an attribute to your `div`s and then add your chart instances to an array which it's key would be that classes. then you are able to call `update` function on your chart's instances like the following:

Html:

```
<div class="chart" ch="chart-one"></div>
<div class="chart" ch="chart-two"></div>
```

js:

```
var $charts = $('.chart');
var charts = {};

$charts.each(function() {
    var key = $(this).attr("ch");
    charts[key] = new Chart($(this), {...});
}
```

Call update function:

```
charts["chart-one"].update();
```